# CoreMediaIO doesn't list iPhone Camera unless QuickTime is open

Tags: ios, swift, macos, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

I have hit the same problem as reported here:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/91266

I'm getting a list of devices connected to my Macbook and displaying my iPhone in a Custom View in macOS app.

```
    let session:AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high

    let listdevices:Array = (AVCaptureDevice.devices())

   // Grabs iOS device on my system change [] for your own Mac
    let device:AVCaptureDevice = listdevices[6]
```

I have set kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices property

```
// Enable access to iOS devices
private func enableDalDevices() {
var property = CMIOObjectPropertyAddress(
    mSelector: CMIOObjectPropertySelector(kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices),
    mScope: CMIOObjectPropertyScope(kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal),
    mElement: CMIOObjectPropertyElement(kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster)
)
var allow: UInt32 = 1
let sizeOfAllow = MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size
CMIOObjectSetPropertyData(CMIOObjectID(kCMIOObjectSystemObject),    &property, 0, nil, UInt32(sizeOfAllow), &allow)
 }
```

If I launch my app then nothing is displayed but if I open Quicktime first and choose file > new movie recording, then launch my app iPhone display shows up fine.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Device not listed by AVCaptureDevice.devices() unless Quicktime is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646470/ios-device-not-listed-by-avcapturedevice-devices-unless-quicktime-is-opened)

Comment: Oh looks like it might