# iOS Device not listed by AVCaptureDevice.devices() unless Quicktime is opened

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, quicktime

I am trying to list the the devices connected to my machine using `AVCaptureDevice.devices()` in a Swift playground.

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import CoreMediaIO

var prop = CMIOObjectPropertyAddress(
    mSelector: CMIOObjectPropertySelector(kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices),
    mScope: CMIOObjectPropertyScope(kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal),
    mElement: CMIOObjectPropertyElement(kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster))

var allow : UInt32 = 1
let dataSize : UInt32 = 4
let zero : UInt32 = 0
CMIOObjectSetPropertyData(CMIOObjectID(kCMIOObjectSystemObject), &prop, zero, nil, dataSize, &allow)


var session = AVCaptureSession()
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.low

let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
for device in devices {
    let deviceID = device.uniqueID
    let deviceName = device.localizedName
    print("\(deviceID): \(deviceName)")
}
```

This gives me the following result even though my iPhone is connected to my computer

```
04-52-c7-c1-65-c4:input: Bose Tito
AppleHDAEngineInput:1B,0,1,0:1: Built-in Microphone
CC26311ECFEG1HNBA: FaceTime HD Camera
```

Now something I've noticed is that if I launch Quicktime Player, select New Movie Recording and selecting my device as a Camera source, then my device is listed

```
04-52-c7-c1-65-c4:input: Bose Tito
AppleHDAEngineInput:1B,0,1,0:1: Built-in Microphone
CC26311ECFEG1HNBA: FaceTime HD Camera
12345b7406eeb053e2d5cded2527315d6110a16e: tito
```

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: I think the device doesn't appear right away, have you tried registering for `AVCaptureDeviceWasConnectedNotification` ?

Comment: You're right. If I print the list of devices again a few seconds later it works. You can add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait a bit for the device to appear.

Register for `AVCaptureDeviceWasConnectedNotification` to be notified once it becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

How did you implement checking that the iOS device was ready to be used?
I have same issue and with a project I am working on.

At the moment if I have quicktime open it works, (i also hard coded the device ID but need to get rid of that)

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    enableDalDevices()

    camera.layer = CALayer()
    let session:AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high
    let listdevices:Array = (AVCaptureDevice.devices())


   // Grabs iOS device on system change value in array [X] depending on devices connected on your own Mac
    let device:AVCaptureDevice = listdevices[6]

 do {
   try session.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device))

    //Preview
    let previewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    let myView:NSView = self.view
    previewLayer.frame = myView.bounds
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight

    self.camera.layer?.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    session.startRunning()

            print(listdevices)

    } catch {

            }


}
```

Comment: see my answer. I think I have been able to give you something you can use

Answer (score 0):

Using @Valerian's answer to help answer @adamprocter, here is how I ended up solving it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    enableDalDevices()

    camera.layer = CALayer()
    let session:AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high

    let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.externalUnknown], mediaType: .muxed, position: .unspecified)
    //You get the devices here and their IDs and do whatever you want
    showDevices(devices: discoverySession.devices)

    //Register for a notification just like @Valerian said earlier
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(newDevice), name: NSNotification.Name.AVCaptureDeviceWasConnected, object: nil)

}

@objc func newDevice() {
    let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.externalUnknown], mediaType: .muxed, position: .unspecified)
    showDevices(devices: discoverySession.devices)
}
```