# How to get iPhone as AVCaptureDevice on macOS?

Tags: swift, iphone, macos, avcapturedevice, core-media

I have implemented the code from the post linked below. However it is not updated to account for AVCaptureDevice.devices() being now deprecated.

[iOS Device not listed by AVCaptureDevice.devices() unless Quicktime is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646470/ios-device-not-listed-by-avcapturedevice-devices-unless-quicktime-is-opened)

Does anyone have a latest implementation of this?

Thank you!

Comment: I see my post was demoted. If someone could point me to the right place where this is solved for the latest version of Swift creating a macOS app I will gladly delete this. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so after doing a combination of some of the other Stack Overflow answers I was able to get it to work with the latest implementation of AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession.

The trick was to call to DiscoverSession to get the devices after enabling Screen Capture Devices. Then adding the observer to look for newly connected devices and it will show.

The previous answers all used the old AVCaptureDevice.devices() method. My example below uses the updated method.

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation
import AVKit
import CoreMediaIO

class PlayerNSView: NSView{
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    private let nc = NotificationCenter.default

    override init(frame:CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)


        let urlVideo = URL(string: "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4")!
        let player = AVPlayer(url: urlVideo)
        //player.play()
        playerLayer.player = player
        if layer == nil{
            layer = CALayer()
        }
        layer?.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        self.enableDalDevices()

        let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.externalUnknown], mediaType: nil, position: .unspecified)



        nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(newDevice), name: NSNotification.Name.AVCaptureDeviceWasConnected, object: nil)

    }

    @objc func newDevice() {
        let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.externalUnknown], mediaType: nil, position: .unspecified)
        print("Devices: \(discoverySession.devices)")
    }



    public func enableDalDevices() {


        var property = CMIOObjectPropertyAddress(mSelector: CMIOObjectPropertySelector(kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices), mScope: CMIOObjectPropertyScope(kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal), mElement: CMIOObjectPropertyElement(kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster))
        var allow : UInt32 = 1
        let sizeOfAllow = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: allow)
        CMIOObjectSetPropertyData(CMIOObjectID(kCMIOObjectSystemObject), &property, 0, nil, UInt32(sizeOfAllow), &allow)

    }


    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func layout() {
        super.layout()

        playerLayer.backgroundColor = .black
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @joeshonm — this works just great!  However I have noticed that the detected `AVCaptureDevice` parameter `formats` is empty in this case and therefore I’m unable to determine an aspect ratio or an appropriate dimension for my view. Any hints on that?

Comment: @ixany This was a long time ago for me, but I believe it's a result of the device type being `.externalUnknown`.

Comment: Great answer, but I don't think you need to use the new device / disconnected notifications - you can also just observe the `AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession`'s `.devices` property!